# How to spearate integer and string from one column into two columns using MySQL?

Tags: mysql, regex

I have one huge table like this

```
id  |  machine
1   |  1 tractor
2   |  1 platform
3   |  2 cylinder
4   |  6 bob cat
5   |  2 excavator
6   |  3 tractor
...
...
```

I want firstly to select only integer from column "machine" AND then select only varchar from column "machine"

It shoul look like this

```
id  |  number          id  |  varchar 
1   |  1               1   |  tractor
2   |  1               2   |  platform
3   |  2               3   |  cylinder
4   |  6               4   |  bob cat
5   |  2               5   |  excavator
6   |  3               6   |  tractor
```

I need two queries for this because I need to sum all integer later and get distinct of varchar.

I have tried this two commands but not working for my problem

```
SELECT machine  FROM machines WHERE machine REGEXP '^[0-9]+$';


SELECT machine FROM machines WHERE machine REGEXP '[a-zA-Z]';
```

Comment: which version of mysql are you using?

Comment: On my localhost using MariaDB 10 , and on my online server using MySQL 5.7.28

Comment: All of the data are like that? or are there some with digit in the middle or at the back?

Comment: All of data are the same, I made the static format and users can't change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `INSTR` with `SUBSTRING`:

```
SELECT
    id,
    machine,
    CAST(SUBSTRING(machine, 1, INSTR(machine, ' ') - 1) AS UNSIGNED) AS machine_id,
    SUBSTRING(machine, INSTR(machine, ' ') + 1) AS machine_name
FROM machines
ORDER BY
    id;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link]

### Demo

The above happens to work well here because `INSTR`, which is not a particularly powerful string function, returns the 1-based index of the *first* occurrence of space, which is the delimiter we want to use here.  Then, we only need to take two substrings to find the machine id and description.

Comment: Thanks, this works fine, I can easily make two query from this. But I need to be sure that this will work without mistake because my database is huge. (It's static format, always "number and machine_name").

Comment: My answer should be stable assuming that every `machine` always have the format of `number text`, with a single space in between the leading number and text.

Answer (score 1):

regardless of how many digits is your number, this solution will help you retrieve the integer value of your column using `+0`. then use string functions to get machine `name` and `number`.

```
select trim(replace(machine  , machine +0, '')) as machine
  ,  machine  +0 as number 
from machines;
```

see [dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=DQ63LrOvqf)

Comment: Nice trick, but note that this approach would fail if the machine names themselves happen to have other numbers in them, [see your updated demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4270ad9a5b9401ad8c7323985ef4ba2e).

Comment: This trick works excellent for now. Very simple query. I hope this won't fail when my database became much more huge. The format of INSERT is static "number and machine_name"